# get variable smarty in php tag

Tags: php, smarty

We want to make date whmcs7
Gregorian dates change from the jalali
That's why we put the following code in the file tpl smarty

```
{$invoice.datecreated}
{php}
    include_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ."/templates/six/jdf.php");
    $date = '{$invoice.datecreated}';
    list($g_y, $g_m, $g_d) = explode("/", $date);
    $str="/";
    print "(".gregorian_to_jalali ($g_y, $g_m, $g_d,$str).")";
{/php}
```

But this piece of code instead of putting on the variable
The insertion string

```
$date = '{$invoice.datecreated}';
print $date;  // result: invoice.datecreated Instead 2015/01/31
```

please guide me

Answer (score 1):

I think you need double quotes.

```
$date = "{$invoice.datecreated}"; //double quotes here as "
print $date;
```

Example:

```
$name = "My name";

echo '{$name}';//outputs {$name}
echo "{$name}";//outputs My name
```

Comment: Correct here, as `"` evaluates the internally specified variables